# checking established ports

Tags: command-line, netstat

Is the command which I am using is wrong to check a port is established or not?

```
count=$(netstat -an | awk '$4 ~ /:'"$PORT"'$/ && $6 == "ESTABLISHED" {print $0}'| wc -l)
```

And taking the `$count > 0` as established?

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure what you mean by "taking the $count > 0 as estalished?", but that looks like a valid count of established connections to a given port. You might want to restrict to a given interface or protocol (so two different services listening on the same port but on different interfaces don't get mixed up).

Additionally, you could also simplify the command a bit:

```
count=$(netstat -an | awk -v port=":$PORT\$" '$4 ~ port && $6 == "ESTABLISHED" {count++} END {print count}')
```

You can also use `lsof` instead. `lsof -i :$PORT` will list open connections on that port, and you can use the `-n` (similar to `-n` in `netstat`), and the `-F T` option (to list PID, file descriptor number and TCP states only) to make it easier to parse:

```
lsof -ni ":$PORT" -FT | grep -c TST=ESTABLISHED
```

Answer (score 0):

Your approach seems to work, however it's not very elegant. I would rather do it this way:

```bsh
if [[ "$(LANG=C netstat -nt | awk -F" +|:" '/ESTABLISHED/{print$5}')" =~ "$PORT" ]]; then
  echo $PORT established
else
  echo $PORT not established
fi
```

The command substitution simply prints the list of established hosts regardless of the user's locale, the conditional expression tests whether `$PORT` is in this list and executes the `then` list if so and the `else` list if not.